# Post form to controller in ASP.NET Core MVC not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to POST a form to my controller the same way that I used to do with ASP.NET MVC 5 but it's not working.

The controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] Login LoginModel)
{
    return View();
}
```

And HTML

```
<form asp-action="Login" asp-controller="Home" method="post" class="mt-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-dark" for="uname">E-mail</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="uname" type="text"
                       placeholder="digite e-mail">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-dark" for="pwd">Senha</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="pwd" type="password"
                       placeholder="digite sua senha">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-dark" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I tried to use the helper:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
{
}
```

But the HTML generated doesn't pass the controller path :

[image]

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
        });
}
```

Comment: it should work. try using this: `<button asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">`

Comment: I did, the same thing! not working!

Comment: Do you have any tags in your class name? can you try adding [Route("Speaker/{id:int}")] to the method?

Comment: Since that's your default route, there shouldn't be a need to post explicitly to `/Home/Login` unless you provided an id value, which you haven't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shows `action="/"` instead of `action="/Home/Login"` on the form since that you have set the default route as `/Home/Login`:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
    });
```

If you change the default route, it will be displayed correctly.

I have tried your code and the problem is in your model binding.

Firstly, you need to remove `[FromBody]` since you are receiving data from a form instead of request body.

Besides, your form does not post data correctly since you do not set the `name` attribute or use `asp-for` tag helper for your inputs which are used to bind inputs' data to model on action parameters.

Finally, see my complete demo with my assumption `Login` model:

```
public class Login
{
    public string uname { get; set; }
    public string pwd { get; set; }
}
```

Login.cshtml( add `name` attribute which equal the `Login` model's property names):

```
<form asp-action="Login" asp-controller="Home" method="post" class="mt-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-dark" for="uname">E-mail</label>
                <input class="form-control" name="uname" id="uname" type="text"
                       placeholder="digite e-mail">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-dark" for="pwd">Senha</label>
                <input class="form-control" name="pwd" id="pwd" type="password"
                       placeholder="digite sua senha">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-dark" />
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

POST action:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(Login LoginModel)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you added

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
});
```

2. Make sure you are calling correct action method
3. In the action method, you are using correct action verb